# UWP MenuFlyout in Application.Resources - how to assign events?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm relatively new to UWP, but I have good WPF background.
What I need is a simple context menu for the application. User "right taps" anywhere, menu opens, user taps an item and things happen.

It looks basic and simple. First I add `MenuFlyout` element to my `Application.Resources`. Then, in `MainPage` I just show it with `ShowAt` method. Works.

To my greatest surprise when I tried to add events to menu items, VS told me it's invalid, events cannot be added in `App.xaml`.

So here's my assignment (in `App.xaml.cs`):

```
MainContextMenu = (MenuFlyout)Resources["MainContextMenu"];
MainContextMenu.Items.First(i => i.Name == "NavToCalibration").Tapped += NavToCalibration_Tapped;
```

The problem is - the handler is never called. I run my app, open the menu, click on the item and nothing happens. The assigned method is not called. What am I doing wrong? Why the handler is not called?

The assignment IS executed on application launch.

I'm also surprised I haven't been able to find any example or tutorial on doing such a simple and basic thing.

There is a good reason I use app-wide context menu instead of other controls. The app displays test images, it has to be full-screen (or maximized window) without interfering elements.

Now I will try to move my menu to the page resources, my pages will have different context menus anyway. But I'm really curious what's wrong in `MenuFlyout` defined in `App.xaml`?

Whoa. I tried to move my `MenuFlyout` to `MainPage`. I was able to assign `Tapped` event in XAML. And it also is not triggered! Now I'm completely lost. Any ideas?

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem both on PC or mobile emulator, my OS version is 10586, and Tapped event of `MenuFlyoutItem` does not fire in the Windows Phone 8.1, but works fine in UWP, can you please try to use Click event instead of Tapped event?

Comment: I used the `Click` event and now it works, however I tested it only with mouse. I don't know if it would work with touch events. What is the correct procedure of making the menu accessible both with mouse and touch, but without duplicating event handlers? Is it possible?

Comment: Ah...there is some problem with the tapped event of `MenuFlyoutItem`, from the info I got before, only for this `MenuFlyoutItem`, the tapped event is considered as click event...It's not right, but click event should work for touch here. Strange thing is I can't reproduce your problem in UWP, this problem should only be in WP8.1, could you please tell me your os version?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise version 1511 build 10586.494 on x64. I use .NET 4.6.1 for this project.

Comment: What you mean by using .NET 4.6.1 for this project? The other things are same as my side. Strange thing.

Comment: My mistake, it's framework version which I normally choose for WPF apps, but it is not relevant to UWP apps, there is only targeting, which is default 10.0 build 10586 (target) and 10.0 build 10240 (min).